# Jenkins + GitHub Plugins webhooks not working

Tags: github, jenkins, webhooks

I'm using latest (v1.10) Jenkins GitHub plugin, Jenkins v1.1
My webhook integration fails with the error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Github Webhook event of type ping is not supported. Only push events are current supported
```

Looks like GitHub is using some kind of 'ping' events, that are not supported. Or there is some configuration missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not use a raw webhook but instead choose "Jenkins (Github plugin)" from the Add Service menu.

Comment: Normal webhooks were working fine until they randomly stopped.. Switching to the plugin as described restored services.

Comment: Problem is, I need Jenkins to respond to **forks**. Just using the Github plugin causes Jenkins to not respond at all to a fork of the repository.

Comment: If you need Jenkins to build forks, you need to add the forks to the job SCM configuration. And the forks also need to have the configuration to notify Jenkins. Forks are no different from the main repository, but you have to remember they do not inherit anything from the main repo.